# Where does MarkLogic 8 cache "user data" on an ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, marklogic

At the time of writing this, currently MarkLogic is supposed to cache user data at `/usr/local/mlcmd.conf`, reference: https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/ec2/CloudFormation

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic 8 currently caches `user data` at `/var/local/mlcmd.conf`. The documentation says `usr/local/mlcmd.conf`. (https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/ec2/CloudFormation)

`/etc/sysconfig/MarkLogic` runs `init-config.sh` (I couldn't find the path of that file), which is said in a comment to write to `/var/local/mlcmd.conf`.

`. init-config.sh  # sets up /var/local/mlcmd.conf and exports marklogic variables`

Comment: What is written to /var/local/*  is not strictly a cache of 'user data'.  It is a cache of resolved values, some of which MAY have originated in 'user data'  -- but also merged with the resolved values from other places as well.   You can validate this by simply not using EC2 'user data', rather configure the managed cluster feature in some other fashion such as /etc/marklogic.conf.   You can follow the exact trail by starting at /etc/init.d/MarkLogic -- all of the managed cluster related functionality  is in plain text scripts (not in the binaries, although not always easy to follow)

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic does not 'cache user-data'.  The scripts referenced (/opt/MarkLogic/mlcmd/*)  do read from user-data, as well as other configuration sources such as /etc/marklogic.conf.   What is 'cached' in  /var/local/mlcmd.conf is the resolved values of the variables documented in https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/ec2/CloudFormation#id_10855 after first initialization of a managed cluster node.  This is intentionally put on the root filesystem so that the lifespan follows the lifecycle of the EC2 instance.  If an instance is terminated and another created to take its place the file will no longer exist and the values re-resolved.   While the documentation focuses on CloudFormation and User Data, none of this has any dependency on either.

Comment: Yeah, it does 'cache' other things there as well.